# Bogus characters for "lsblk" but only in terminal, not over SSH?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, ssh

See screenshots.  What's going on here?

On the terminal (IPMI console window - it mirrors exactly what's on the screen):

[image: Terminal output of lsblk]

Via SSH in to the same box:

[image: SSH output of lsblk]

Locale output for reference:

```
root@ubuntu16:~# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
root@ubuntu16:~#
```

Due to a comment from Serg, I gave some settings a try, and it appears using "LC_CTYPE=C" before lsblk makes it look correct:

[image]

Why does LC_CTYPE alter the output for the actual terminal, but it's unnecessary for the SSH terminal?

Comment: And what if you do locally `LC_ALL=C lsblk`  ?

Comment: That makes it look more normal - what is LC_ALL?

Comment: Variable assignment before a command, places that variable into command's environment, so it makes `lsblk` run with basic English locale only.   So yeah, you do have locale issue there - we now know that much, although I'm not sure what to suggest to fix it.

Comment: I just notices you have `LANGUAGE=en_US` there, but the others are `en_US.UTF-8` Consider editing that value in `/etc/default/locale` file. That might help

Comment: That didn't change anything for me, I'll update the main question

Comment: Your "terminal" looks like a Windows console (which is _not_ a terminal or terminal emulator in any meaningful sense). If that is indeed the case you must make sure that the character encoding used by `lsblk` (taken from `LANG`, `LANGUAGE` or `LC_ALL`) matches the console code page.

Comment: @Locane What terminal or console are you using?

Comment: @AlexP that's a screensnip of the IPMI window.  It's orange because of the 16.04 bug that fails to properly close a color tag after it boots - other terminals are white and fine.

The IPMI window is default Ubuntu shell - I assume Bash.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the locale temporarily, you should run the following command instead:

```
LC_ALL=C lsblk
```

Alternatively, if you face this issue with other terminal outputs too, you might want to set this globally with the following command:

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

For more details on what exactly `LC_ALL=C` does, you can look at this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do).

Answer (score 0):

After long digging I figure it out! Probably its correct way.

Permanent fixed by changing:

`/etc/default/console-setup`

```
CHARMAP="iso-8859-15"
CODESET="guess"
```

TO

```
CHARMAP="UTF-8"
CODESET="guess"
```

You can also use `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`

After change better REBOOT!